# How to add a big repository to Git

Tags: git

I have a project with millions of files and all those files are code, not content. Believe it or not, but this project is currently not using any source control...

I would like to put it under source control and I chose Git as we use it for other projects. The problem is that the repository seems to be too big for Git to handle.

I could probably split it in multiple "subproject" but is it possible to link all those "subproject" together?

**EDIT**

Check this discussion. I basically have that situation, a project with several GB of data, but all the files are source code.

[Is Git recommended for large (>250GB) content repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999744/is-git-recommended-for-large-250gb-content-repositories)

Comment: Just try to create your repo and git commit ! why would you believe git cannot handle ? your repo should deliver something, in java it can be jar/war for example, you would use subproject when this subproject delivers a jar file

Comment: What are the symptoms of "too big for Git to handle"?  In general, you "link all those subprojects together" using git [submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).

Comment: Symptom of too large? Example : Git tried to commit for hours without success...

Comment: I've read your other comments, and I don't believe all of the over 300G of files are source code files. (I might be mistaken because I don't know your system.) If this is the case, consider adding only true source code files and exclude images, documents and data-dumps and other binary files (eg executable files) and vendor supplied files for now. This will allow all your users to clone the source code and get the other files using other means (eg ftp). Later one, you can start adding more important files slowly, making the transition to a version control system much more palatable.

Comment: I also find it hard to believe that a project that uses no source code control could have 300G of non-machine-generated source code.  That's 75 times the size of Mozilla!

Comment: @crafter You are partially right. It is 300GB but... That's what happen when instead of deleting stuff that you change you just put it in comments or make backup files for everything that change instead of relying on a version control. Then the application support multiple language and the code is also duplicated for every language but still coupled with the "core". Truth is if we were to take the time to delete all the useless stuff and the duplication, we would probably keep only 1%...

Comment: @Gudradain, then look into the power of gitignore as well. For example, if your source files are named (assume they are C source files) map.c, map.c.copy, map.c,copy.copy, map.copy.20140101.c and so on (you get the picture?), then you can force git to only consider map.c. You can by excluding as much as you can, and slowly add the rest. The important thing for you is to get a reasonable starting point.

Comment: In addition, if you want to keep the 3G situation, but want to share the code with others without using the network, then look into using git bundle. This allows you to create a "bundle" that you can transport on a disk and then clone in on another machine : https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-bundle.html. If you are keen in this approach I will put this into an answer to make it usable.

Comment: @crafter Only adding what is really required with .gitignore might be a good compromise. It will take time to add everything that is used but it also takes time to delete all the useless stuff. I was kinda hoping that GIT had some magical solution for the mess we dig ourselves in... (and I hate working without a source control)

Answer (score 2):

Git doesn't have any limitation on file size or file count in the repository.

With that being said, if you have portions of your git repository that has a break in dependency and naturally could logically be a part of itself, consider using [submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).  And it sounds like from your below comment that you are away of the nature of this project, and are already hinting at *submodules*.

> I could probably split it in multiple "subproject" but is it possible to link all those "subproject" together?

Ultimately, my recommendation here would be to **try it out**.  I'm not sure where your fears are being rooted from, but just give the project a go by initializing it as a git repository.

Comment: Thx for the answers. I tried to initialize it as a Git repository. It couldn't get pass the initial commit even if you waited for an entire day.

Comment: @Gudradain what happens?  Git just hangs?

Comment: Pretty much. It freezes forever. I tried doing it via command line and via GUI like source tree, both freeze.

Comment: @Gudradain I just saw that your "project" is 300 GB. Is that all really one single project??

Comment: @Gudradain What exactly did Git hang on?  `$ git init` or `$ git commit`?

Comment: Actually yes. It should probably be hundred of projects but the developers that came before me had the nice idea to mixed everything together. So while, one section should be independent, it actually calls functions all across the code base and everything is "nicely" coupled. Hence, you cannot really split it unless you throw it away or do heavy refactor. So yes, one project.

Comment: @Gudradain It sounds like submodules are what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I have big projects (2GB+). Git can handle it just fine.

The only issue i found is because of slow network connection (VPN). Specially if developer wants to clone project. But once project is cloned, pull and push are working from VPN just fine.

Comment: It's more about a repository that is over 300GB.

Comment: Double check with Administrator: I am using Atlassian Stash and it has a project and repository disk size limit.

Comment: One trick: I create a project then add files and directories little by little. It takes a long time and many many commits but works better. I have done this in Git and SVN.